# Deleting max value of different names in sql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
Name    Value   Date
A   10  2016
A   20  2017
A   30  Null
B   40  2015
B   50  2014
B   60  Null
C   70  2017
C   80  2018
C   90  2019
```

I want to find max value of corresponding names which have Dates. If date is null that row should be deleted and the next corresponding value to be considered and displayed.

I have got max value but not able to delete that row

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select name,max(val)
from tablename
where date is not null
group by name
```